# How to assign data from a file to a dictionary?

Tags: python, file, dictionary

I am just starting my coding adventure. My problem is that I have a file with structure:

```
% program   : RTKPOST 
% pos mode  : ppp-static
% solution  : forward
% elev mask : 10.0 deg
% dynamics  : off
% tidecorr  : off
% tropo opt : saastamoinen
% ephemeris : broadcast
% ====================================  END OF HEADER
```

and I would like the code to return a dictionary `{program: "RTKPOST", pos_mode : "ppp-static"}`

I was trying:

```
data = []
header = {}

with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("%"):
            key, val = line.split()
            header[key] = val
        else:
            data.append(line.split())
```

and got:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Comment: Have you made an attempt that might indicate at which level you have problem? Its hard to get an appropriate answer without that. For example, do you know how to open a file? Do you know how to iterate over the file? Do you know how to construct any `Dict` at all?

Comment: That's an inconvenient format.  Where did this file come from?  You might want to start with generating a file that'll be easier to parse (e.g. JSON or CSV).

Comment: @L.Grozinger edited

Comment: You can't unpack data to `key, value` like that. Try something like `split_value = line.split(":")`  an then `header[split_value[0]] = split_value[1]`

Comment: then I got `IndexError: list index out of range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax `x, y = z` can be used to assign to both `x` and `y` using the values in `z`, but it expects that `z` has the correct number of values available (in this case 2). This works e.g.

```
>>> x, y = [1, 2]
>>> x
1
>>> y
2
```

But this does not:

```
>>> x, y = [1, 2, 3]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Since each of your `line.split()`s have more than 2 values, `key, val = line.split()` will always produce this error. The problem is, that e.g. the last line of the file doesn't follow the same rules as the first lines. In general, this approach will not be robust.

I suggest instead using regular expressions to pick out the key-value pairs you want. In this way you can easily specify the format that the key-value pairs have in the file, and extract them from the whole file easily, if the format changes in the future, just change the regular expression.

I suggest the regular expression:

```
header_property = r'^% (.+):(.+)$'
```

To interpret this regular expression, take a look at the [re docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). In short, this will match lines that start with `%` , followed by strings of one or more characters with a `:` in the middle.

A full example using this is as follows:

```
import re
header_property = r'^% (.+):(.+)$'

header = {}

with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        match = re.search(header_property, line)
        if match is not None:
            key = match.group(1).strip()
            value = match.group(2).strip()
            header[key] = value
```

After which `header` will be

```
>>> header
{'program': 'RTKPOST', 'pos mode': 'ppp-static', ..., 'ephemeris': broadcast'}
```

Pretty much anything can be extracted from text files using regular expressions. It is worthwhile learning a bit about how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

- Split on `':'` since that's what separates your keys from your values.
- Make sure not to try to split/parse that `END OF HEADER` line.

```
data = []
header = {}

with open("file.txt") as file:
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith("% =="):
            break
        if not line.startswith("%"):
            data.append(line.split())
            continue
        key, val = map(str.strip, line[1:].split(':'))
        header[key] = val

print(header)
```

prints:

```
{'program': 'RTKPOST', 'pos mode': 'ppp-static', 'solution': 'forward', 'elev mask': '10.0 deg', 'dynamics': 'off', 'tidecorr': 'off', 'tropo opt': 'saastamoinen', 'ephemeris': 'broadcast'}
```